# Android - Getting waypoint coordinates from Google maps webview

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, webview, google-maps-android-api-2

I am creating a Android app which will load the google map to webview. Than the user can create their own route by clicking (set waypoints) on map. 
Google supports up to 8 waypoint.

My question is, how can I handle the "click event" from map (set waypoint) and get the [*lat, lon*] of this waypoint? The goal is to store the clicked waypoints in array.

So far I did not find any tutorial which shows how can be added multiple waypoints into google maps from webview.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is enable the click listener using [OnMapClickListener](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/events#map_click_long_click_events).
When a user clicks (taps) somewhere on the map, you will receive an onMapClick(LatLng) event that indicates the location on the map that the user clicked

It's now up to you to store the LatLng values that the event has returned.
Here's a snippet from this Google [sample](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/EventsDemoActivity.java):

```
   @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        mMap = map;
        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
        mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
        mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(this);
    }
    //'point' holds the value of LatLng coordinates
    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
        mTapTextView.setText("tapped, point=" + point);
    }
```

Here's the version in Javascript

```
function initMap() {
  var myLatlng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng
  });

  map.addListener('click', function(e) {
     console.log("clicked at  " + e.latLng);
  });
}
```

In this simple [fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4wz4z17j/2/), if you click on the map and check your console log, you will see the exact coordinates where the event happened. So going back to your situation, if you click on a waypoint, you will know where it is located.

Comment: Thank you, your answer is correct in case I will use GoogleMaps API for android. But my goal is to use the Google maps in webview. Something similar to this [link](http://gebweb.net/optimap/). Creating a custome route by adding waypoints to the map.

Comment: your Android tag confused me, ok, I'll make you a Javascript sample for WebView.